# gitk not working inside of tmux

Tags: macos, terminal, git, tmux

I have a weird issue where `gitk` does not run when I use it inside of a `tmux` session. If I run `gitk` from `tmux`, I get:

```
Error in startup script: 58:102: execution error: An error of type -10810 has occurred. (-10810)
    while executing
"exec osascript -e [format {
    tell application "System Events"
        set frontmost of processes whose unix id is %d to true
    end te..."
invoked from within
"if {[tk windowingsystem] eq "aqua"} {
    exec osascript -e [format {
        tell application "System Events"
            set frontmost of processes ..."
    (file "/usr/local/bin/gitk" line 12019)
```

However, if I run this in a normal terminal (no `tmux`), it works perfectly as it should.

I've installed both `tmux` and `git` using brew and I am running on Mac OSX 10.10.1. `tmux -v` shows 2.0 and `git --version` shows 2.5.0.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe related to http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-gitk-workaround-Tcl-Tk-Cmd-TAB-behavior-on-OSX-td7582264.html ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to install/update reattach-to-user-namespace

if you are using brew you can do that using following command.

```
brew upgrade reattach-to-user-namespace
```

[this has something to do with osascript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174779/unable-to-run-display-notification-using-osascript-in-a-tmux-session)